# would it reflect badly if I asked a former supervisor to contact a potential new manager?

Tags: hiring-process

Would it reflect badly if I asked my former supervisor to contact my potential new employer/manager. 
I was terminated from my last job. She (former supervisor) was not in favor of the decision. She still ralleys for me and speaks well of me. She has offered to give a high recommendation. 
I know that she is NOTHING the person HR will contact when checking former employers. 
Gaaah! What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and No.

You should be OK to list your former supervisor as a reference.  It sounds as though she would be very willing to give you a good recommendation.  If you haven't already, you should ask her if you can list her as a reference.

But you should not ask your former supervisor to contact potential employers because this is backwards.  The generally accepted way to connect potential employers to references is to give (with permission) the contact information of your reference to the prospective employer (typically as part of your application or upon request).

Answer (score 0):

If your former supervisor is willing to be a reference then list your supervisor by name and direct phone number as a reference on your resume.